# Splitting string with 3rd bracket?

Tags: c#, string, split

How can I split some comma separated braced values in C#?

e.g : How to split `"[1,2,3],[4,5]"` to `"1,2,3"` and `"4,5"` in C#?

Comment: `string[] sets = Regex.Split(value, "],\[");` `foreach(string set in sets) set = set.trim("\[]"`);

Comment: Does the nesting is only one level deep, or is it arbirary? Is `[[1,[2,3]]],[4,[5,6],7]` allowed?

Comment: Or split on the comma, then use trim() to get rid of the [ ].

Comment: How about simply splitting it on `],[` ?

Comment: @Viezevingertjes That won't work as it will split on every comma. They want to only split on the comma that is surrounded by the brackets

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Why would you need to escape a square bracket?

Comment: @juharr Because it's regex, that's a key character. Though I shouldn't have done it on the trim

Comment: Along with knowing if there is nesting would you ever have single values not in brackets like "[1, 2], 3, [4, 5]"?

Comment: @Draken You do realize you can just use `string.Split` then.

Comment: @juharr It was off the top of my head, I'm sure the user gets the idea now

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, Yeah,  one level deep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method and LINQ:

```
string str = "[1,2,3],[4,5]";
var res = str.Split(new[] { "],[" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
             .Select(c => c.Replace("[", "").Replace("]","")).ToArray();
```

Input:

> [1,2,3],[4,5]

Output:

> 1,2,3
>
> 4,5

Input:

> [[1,[2,3]]],[4,[5,6],7]

Output:

> 1,2,3
>
> 4,5,6,7

Comment: @S.Akbari: Thanks :)

Comment: Ok I'understand, Thank, I remove my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to understand the algorithm for such a problem, this might help you: (I tested my code with the input and it works.)

```
public static string[] Split(string s)
{
    List<string> strings = new List<string>();
    int index = 0;
    while (index < s.Length)
    {
        if (s.Substring(index, 1) == "[")
        {
            int length = s.IndexOf("]", index + 1) - (index + 1);
            string s2 = s.Substring(index + 1, length);
            strings.Add(s2);
            index += s2.Length + 2;
        }
        else index++;
    }
    return strings.ToArray();
}
```

This is not to say that the other answer is not useful. Sometimes linq can be quite helpful. Also, my code is for learning only, I didn't put any error checking in, etc. and assumes a case [as you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37747120/splitting-string-with-3rd-bracket/37748511#comment62964843_37747120) of no nesting.

Comment: Thanks man! Thanks for the implementation of the algorithm.  :)